# What problem might I have with this post method code?

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with the following php code. I am trying to submit password, while submission is successful the echo part of php to be displayed on webpage but am not getting any error or response.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>POST METHOD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        Please enter your password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" value="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
    $password='password';
    if(isset($_POST['password']) &&!empty($_POST['password'])){
        echo 'submtted and filled';
    }
?>
```

Comment: are these two segments of code in the same file? and is that file called `login.php`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong name for post: you need to use `pwd` instead of `password`

```
if(isset($_POST['pwd']) && !empty($_POST['pwd'])){

     echo 'submtted and filled';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to use name in post metho, to get value of any text/other fields. But in your code you are using type(password) that's why your password not coming in server side. You can use below code, I hope it may works

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>POST METHOD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        Please enter your password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" value="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['pwd']) && $_POST['pwd'] !='')
{
  echo 'submtted and filled';
}
 else
{
   echo 'Something went wrong please try again';
}


?>
```